# How to generate html code for table in C# Net 6

Tags: c#, html, datatable, .net-6.0

I have some legacy C# code running on .NET Framework 4.8. It generates a table class (in `System.Web.UI`) and uses `HtmlTextWriter` and `RenderControl` methods to generate the html code for that table. The html scripts are used in email body (not website) and so I do need the html code.

Now the trouble is in .NET 6, `System.Web.UI` is no longer supported. Please suggest some solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [HtmlTextWriter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlTextWriter/) nuget package.

Since it is a reimplementation, it may not match exactly the generated HTML of your old code, but it might be worth giving it a try.

Comment: But, what about table class?

Comment: Table class is probably just a wrapper that generates the table HTML. You would have to generate the table HTML yourself by using the HtmlTextWriter.